# Strange behavior with std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I am trying to implement a matrix template class using std::vector.

Code:

```
// matrix.h
template <class T>
class matrix
{
public:
    ~matrix(void);
    matrix(int rows, int cols):_rows(rows),_cols(cols){ _size = _rows*_cols;init();} // 

private:
    matrix(void);
    void init(); // sets up _matirx 

    //DATA
    size_t _rows;
    size_t _cols;
    std::vector<T> _matrix;
}

// continued in matrix.tpp file
template <class T>
void matrix<T>::init(){
    _matrix = std::vector<T>(_rows*_cols);
    for(size_t i = 1; i <= _rows ;i++){
        for(size_t j = 1 ; j <= _cols ; j++){
            _matrix[(i - 1)*_rows + (j - 1 )] = 0 ; 
        }   
    }   
}


template <class T>
matrix<T>::matrix(const matrix<T>& rhs)
{
    _matrix = rhs._matrix;
    _rows = rhs._rows;
    _cols = rhs._cols;
}



//in Source.cpp

matrix<int> ABC  = matrix<int>(4,2) ;  
// Gives Debug Assertion Failed , subscript error in VS

matrix<int> ABC  = matrix<int>(4000,4000) ;// Works , No Error

matrix<int> ABC  = matrix<int>(2,4) ; // Works No Error
```

I know about using push_back , I will re implement the class using it , but I was wondering , why it works in the last two cases , and does not in the first case ? My hunch is that in the first case some elements are not being initialized. Is there a restriction in std::vector that say for index i , i+1 th element has to be initialized before the i+2 element is initialized ? 
Or is there something more subtle going on ?

- Thank you

Comment: There's no need for you to explicitly set every element to 0, `std::vector` will do that for you.

Comment: @dreamlax but if I don't set i th element to zero and use vec[i] , won't that give me a compile error ? Is there any way to set the maximum size of the   vec ? so that I can index with out worries ? -thanks

Comment: Don't use 1-based for loops, they are confusing and anti-idiomatic.

Comment: `_matrix[(i - 1)*_rows + (j - 1 )]` the subscript computation is incorrect. You want the current column index `j-1` plus the current row index times the number of **columns**. That is, `_matrix[(i-1)*_cols + (j-1)]`

Comment: @n.m for a martix it is more natural to call (1,1) rather than (0,0) , this is why I used them. Yep , they are confusing . thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @dyp ah.. so that was my mistake , I will try it out and report

Comment: @nnrales This (1,1) vs (0,0) is something you specify to the outside. You don't need to use 1-based indexing internally. In fact, I think you shouldn't use 1-based indexing internally, since `std::vector` uses 0-based indexing. An `operator()` accessor can translate from a 1-based interface to a 0-based implementation.

Comment: Btw your code will not compile, it lacks a definition of `_size`.

Comment: @dyp your solution worked. Yes I am overloading the () operator like you said , the user might say 1,1 I convert it into 0,0 and store it .

Comment: @dyp I forgot when I copied it. I was trying to keep the code short.

Comment: Your `init` function is not needed at all, you can initialize the matrix in the constructor: `matrix(int rows, int cols): _rows(rows),  _cols(cols), _matrix(rows*cols, 0) {}`

Comment: @n.m thanks for the tip. I am just starting out in C++. if it is not too much any good resource you would recommend ?

Comment: Get "Accelerated C++" by Koenig and Moo, it's the best C++ book I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you may have out-of-bounds access:

```
_matrix = std::vector<T>(_rows*_cols);
for(size_t i = 1; i <= _rows ;i++){
    for(size_t j = 1 ; j <= _cols ; j++){
        _matrix[(i - 1)*_rows + (j - 1 )] = 0 ; 
    }   
}
```

Take your examples during the last loop execution:

- with 4x2 size: i-1 = 3, _rows = 4 and j-1 = 1, hence you're accessing the 13-th element of your vector of size 8.
- with 4000x4000 size, you're accessing the (4000-1)*4000+(4000-1)=15999999-th element over 16000000, hence no out of bounds access.

Same goes for the last example.

Answer (score 2):

Simple typo.

```
_matrix[(i - 1)*_rows + (j - 1 )] = 0 ;
```

should be

```
_matrix[(i - 1)*_cols + (j - 1 )] = 0;
```

Working it through on paper for each iteration of the loops would have revealed this.

Comment: could you explain why the last two cases work , even though this error existed ?

Comment: Hiura gave me the answer , I will upvote this answer when I have enough rep points. Thank you for the reply.